# How to format date column with timezone in mongoexport as csv?

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

I am unable to format date based column in output --

```
mongoexport --host 127.0.0.1 --port 27017 -u multichannel -p Password@1234 --authenticationDatabase multichannel --db multichannel --collection sms_response_packets  --skip 0 --limit 100000 --sort='{"_id": 1}' --type=csv --query='{"user_id":{"$in":["1"]},"sent_at":{"$gte":{"$date":"2020-04-29T18:30:00.000Z"},"$lte":{"$date":"2020-11-30T18:29:59.000Z"}},"campaign_id":{"$in":["5fa6860bde52be3bc4cb7558"]}}' --fields="channel,status_text,message_nationality,recipient,sender_id,sent_at.toDate(),msg_splits,message_text"  --out /var/www/html/multichannel-gateway/uploads/mis-export/5fbb5646a8a94f748c44e2e8/341.csv
```

in above column `sent_at` is date to which i need to format in date like '12-10-2020 10AM' as per timezone and date here stored as ISO dateformat.

and csv output as --

```
sms,Submitted,national,919087267198,SMS-TWO,2020-09-10T13:13:49.783Z,,
```

Comment: Does `sent_at.toDate()` produce `2020-09-10T13:13:49.783Z` or what?

Comment: imho the only option is to add a field setting the date in the format you want, and exporting that field

Comment: You can create a view, where you can specify the format for the date field (i.e., a string like '12-10-2020 10AM'), and then use the view to export.

Comment: @minsky sent_at.toDate() is producing empty value, while sent_at contains the date value